# pause until - Condition || Microsoft Flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, power-automate

Which action is associated with Pause Until Action (SharePoint Designer)  - with Microsoft Flow?

i would like to use this in Microsoft Flow for a condition "But cannot find one"

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found that - Delay, Delay Until can be used in place of that from Microsoft Flow